# Google Ical import for our Azure web app fails

Tags: azure, google-calendar-api, icalendar

We have developed a SaaS solution on Windows Azure. We generate Ical feeds for the appointments in our applications for every user.

The Ical seems to work on outlook, iphone etc. 
Google calendar is the only one where it does not work.

We work with a SSL certicate signed by GoDaddy. 
When working with a normal http connection the Ical seems to work like normal.

I would assume google accepts the certificates from GoDaddy but there still seems to be a problem?

I had different situations:

- Our events pop up but then disappear again and we get the error:  'Could not fetch the URL'
- Or our events pop up but we keep getting the message 'Importing calendar for URL'. That message stays there forever. When refreshing our events will stay but will not be updated.
- Validating the Ical with http://severinghaus.org/projects/icv/ works.
- Downloading the .ics and inserting it manually works as well.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Kevin,

Google is having an issue right now with all iCal feeds, which is most likely the cause of your problem. The symptons are just as you described, they show up and then disappear.

Google hasn't come out and admitted anything yet, but it's obviously something on there end. Hopefully we get a fix soon, I'm in the same boat as you.

You can follow the issue here:

http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/calendar/tB7ICbqeLpo

Comment: It's a similiar problem but not quite that becuase I had the problem long before today. I found one solution thou where I shorten my Ical HTTPS url with a bit.ly url. Then everything works but like you said. Once it refreshes it's gone again.

Answer (score 0):

Problem seems to be related to your SSL certificate. Similar question was answered here [Google calendar can't import my ical file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19764216/google-calendar-cant-import-my-ical-file/21459955#21459955)