# Google calendar can't import my ical file

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, google-calendar-api, icalendar

Assume I have some controller "Controller" and public method in it:

```
public ActionResult GetICal(int? param1, int? param2)
{
    string cal = "";
    //some logic goes here
    return File(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(cal), "text/calendar", "calendar.ics");
}
```

Then I'm trying to export it to Google Calendar via url: https://my.site.com/controller/getIcal?param1=0&param2=1

And then nothing happens. Once i've got message like "Can't fetch url" (or simething like that).

I don't know, what I'm doing wrong. This url is 100% accessible without authorization. And if I'm adding this calendar via file, everything is going ok (so calendar has correct format).

Comment: why do you have ? on your int parameters

Comment: It's just sample. Really I'm passing here start/finish dates and some information for selecting necessary events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same problem now - what I had to change, and what is the problem as I see it, is parameters in my url. With any parameters it always end up with error message "Can't fetch url".

But when I used google URL shrinker, and added calendar as this shrinked URL, like http://goo.gl/XXXXX, it worked on first try.

Answer (score 1):

What type of SSL certificate has your server? Self-signed? We had similar issue:

1. when we used normal "http", iCal feed was imported correctly
2. when we used "https" with self-signed certificate, Google Calendar did not import the feed,
   but with goo.gl service as mentioned ppetak it was OK
3. when we used "https" with Class 2 certificate verified by GoDaddy.com, situation was same as in 2)
4. when we used "https" with Class 3 certificate verified by VeriSign everything works properly

Comment: Ye, we're using self-signed certificate. Now it makes sense.